# How can I show that this Jacobi polynomial can be expressed as the sum of these two Legendre polynomials?

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$ be a positive integer.  Let $L_n\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the $n$'th order [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).  Let $J_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the $n$'th order [Jacobi polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials) with weights $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

How can I show that

$$2J_n^{(0,-1)}(x) = L_n(x) + L_{n-1}(x)$$ and that

$$2J_n^{(-1,0)}(x) = L_n(x) - L_{n-1}(x).$$

I have tried to prove this mainly by starting with the Rodriguez formulas and attempting to show that they are equal.  Another attempt was to show that the family of polynomials $\{L_n+L_{n-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is orthogonal with respect to the Jacobi differential equation's weighted inner product.

I can flesh these attempts out if anyone desires, but they seem to be dead ends.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your unusual notation (normally the Legendre polynomals are denoted with $P_n$ and $P_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}$ are the Jacobi polynomials), you have (see [DLMF, equation 19.7.9](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.7.E9) or [Abramowitz/Stegun 22.5.35](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_779.htm))
$$L_n(x) = J_n^{(0,0)}(x)$$
Use the recurrence relations for Jacobi polynomials ([DLMF, equation 18.9.5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.9.E5) or A/S [22.7.18 and 22.7.19](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_782.htm))
$$(2n+\alpha+\beta)J_n^{(\alpha-1, \beta)}(x)=
(n+\alpha+\beta)J_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x)-(n+\beta)J_{n-1}^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x)
$$
$$(2n+\alpha+\beta)J_n^{(\alpha, \beta-1)}(x)=
(n+\alpha+\beta)J_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x)+(n+\alpha)J_{n-1}^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x)
$$
For $\alpha=\beta=0,\;n\ne 0\;$ they reduce to 
$$2J_n^{(-1, 0)}(x)=
J_n^{(0, 0)}(x)-J_{n-1}^{(0, 0)}(x)
$$
$$2J_n^{(0, -1)}(x)=
J_n^{(0, 0)}(x)+J_{n-1}^{(0, 0)}(x)
$$
Now compute
$$L_n(x)+L_{n-1}(x)=J_n^{(0, 0)}(x)+J_{n-1}^{(0, 0)}(x) = 2J_n^{(0, -1)}(x)$$
$$L_n(x)-L_{n-1}(x)=J_n^{(0, 0)}(x)-J_{n-1}^{(0, 0)}(x) = 2J_n^{(-1, 0)}(x)$$

Comment: do you know of a reference where they might derive this relationship?

Comment: There is some material in A. Erdély et al., Higher Transcendental Functions Vol. II; available via the reference link at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project.  
In Ch. 10.8 Orthogonal Polynomials they say _(vii) Miscellaneous results. We may apply Christoffel's formula ..._ The recurrence relations used above are their formulas (35) and (36).

Comment: The DLMF gives [Rainville](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=IO5QAAAAMAAJ) as the reference for the recurrence in $\alpha$ or $\beta$.